# responsive image and text within border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

Having problem styling the border.

[What i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNvt.png)

[What i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQlbr.jpg)

HTML codes

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ac/row_ac001_m0.jpg">
            <div class="caption">
                <p align="center"><b>Model No.Row-AC-001</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <img class="col-sm-2 img-responsive" src="images/ac/row_ac002_m0.jpg">
        <img class="col-sm-2 img-responsive" src="images/ac/row_ac003_m0.jpg">
<!---continues------>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
    .thumbnail {
    border:1px;
    width:15%;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Comment: your `.row` element should be on its own below `.container`

Comment: you should specify height to maintain the same height and width for all the cards and padding to have a good room for the item elements

Comment: You didn't used class thumbnail in your code

Comment: @shas .. I believe he did.

Comment: make sure to give a height/width and `display:block` to your `img` elements.

Comment: Much appreciated. @CodeGodie I will edit that, but what's the problem with that? Could you explain abit?

Comment: The reason for `display:block` is to treat the img element as a block element, as its normally an inline element. This will help in removing any weird spacing around it. Its also recommended to use a fixed height because some images may be bigger than others. You may have to tweak this as needed if you want your result to be responsive.

Comment: However, since you're already using Bootstrap, by using the `.thumbnail` class, the `img` element should automatically be set as `display:block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.thumbnail{
   border: thin gray solid;
   border-radius: 0px !important;
   margin: 0 5px;
  }

  .image_size{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   display: block;
  }

p{
  font-size:12px;
  }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
     <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" class="img-responsive image_size">
          <p class="text-center">Your Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>


    </div>
```

**PS:** Change your image size as per your need.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca5qj0ho/6/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use html this way:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ac/row_ac002_m0.jpg">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p align="center"><b>Model No.Row-AC-001</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- First col -->

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ac/row_ac002_m0.jpg">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p align="center"><b>Model No.Row-AC-001</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Second col -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Use CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
     border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

Comment: just for class, why he have to add extra div tag ?

Comment: its Bootstrap my friend.

Comment: Because we need to space between grids.

Comment: I don understand why people downvoted this answer. This is the right way to do it with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the photos you provided.**

The wider the screen, the more items per line.

```css
.myitem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 310px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.mycoolcontainer,
.myitem {
  margin: .4em;
}
img,
.mycoolcontainer,
.myitem {
  max-width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycoolcontainer">
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
    <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
  <div class="myitem">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">Title
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code and appended below. I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

The formation should be like this, the grid size based on your requirement. You can change the grid size.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/22/05/41/muang-sing-historical-park-1924558__340.jpg" alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <p class="text-center">Row-AC-001</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail img {
 max-width: 150px;
}

.thumbnail .caption {
 padding-top: 9px;
}
```

Codepen link attached,

http://codepen.io/WebTechie/pen/vyMqdY